# Ajax get within title section of a

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<div class="slidera_img"> 
<a href="/image1.jpg" rel="example_group" title="<a href='#'><img src='/vote.png' style='float:left; margin-left:45%;' /></a>">
</div
```

I have the above code, which open a fancy box modal window, inside the modal window there is a button which is used to vote an item. I want to be able to do this via ajax. currently, i m doing on server side, with new request but i want to use jquery ajax.

As you can see second a resides within title tag. How can i access that so upon click on that, i can trigger an ajax call?

I have the code that works without the modal windows as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxpost(id) {
            var item = $(this);

            $.get('@Url.Action("VoteAjax","Home")', { id: id }, function (response) {
                item.closest("li").find(".slidera_num").html(response.vote);
            });
        }
</script>
```

EDIT: I was able to use above and do ajax call after adding

```
title="<a href='#' onClick='ajaxpost(1)'>...
```

Comment: `title` is an attribute. How do you set an HTML element to it?

Comment: well that s how fancybox works.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Why not? However, it will look awful.

Comment: it s terrible and that s how fancybox does it. and that s what designer gave me. :(